Python- How to concatenate multiple lines?
I use Python 3.12.1
I would like to concatenate  blocks of lines, as if they were on the "same" line
x = "#" + "#" + "\\n" + "#"

##  
#

I would like to obtain something similar to
####  
# #  

(like a x +x)
I tried
print(x, end = "")  
print(x)

but i have:
##  
###  
#

(its normal because the second print continue after the "\n" of the 1st one)
